# Usage of MongoDB Aggregation queries in Apache beam

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I am trying to use Aggregation query as part of Apache Beam MongoDBIO QueryFn.But I dont get any results back.

```
List<BsonDocument> documents = new ArrayList<>();
documents.add(
       new BsonDocument(
              "$group",
               new BsonDocument("_id", new BsonString("$field_name1"))
                   .append("count", new BsonDocument("$sum", new BsonString("field_name2")))
         ));

 pipeline.apply(MongoDbIO.read()
          .withUri("mongodb://localhost:27017")
          .withDatabase("databaseName")
          .withCollection("collectionName")
          .withQueryFn(AggregationQuery.create().withMongoDbPipeline(documents)));
```

Is the query structure correct?

Comment: The syntax looks fine on the first sight.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using BsonString, you should use the appropriate BsonValue subclass for each field in the pipeline. For example, to specify a string value, you should use BsonString. To specify a numeric value, you should use BsonInt32, BsonInt64, or another numeric type depending on the data type of your field.

```
List<BsonDocument> documents = new ArrayList<>();
documents.add(
    new BsonDocument(
        "$group",
        new BsonDocument("_id", new BsonString("$field_name1"))
            .append("count", new BsonDocument("$sum", new BsonInt32(1))) // use BsonInt32 instead of BsonString
    )
);

pipeline.apply(MongoDbIO.read()
    .withUri("mongodb://localhost:27017")
    .withDatabase("databaseName")
    .withCollection("collectionName")
    .withQueryFn(AggregationQuery.create().withMongoDbPipeline(documents))
);
```